# JavaFX MediaPlayer stutters on Mac with mp4 files

Tags: macos, javafx, media-player

To reproduce the problem you can use the JavaFX sample project AdvancedMedia. Replace the flv video with a mp4 one which encoding type is [supported](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html#SupportedMediaTypes) by JavaFX.

Edit: I thought maybe people are having trouble to edit the sample. Just place a video in the project root folder and set `MEDIA_URL` to `new File("video.mp4").toURI().toString()`.

It works great on Windows platforms. However, on Mac the video stutters in the beginning and before it ends. When running the project on terminal with `java -jar AdvancedMedia.jar` it shows the following messages:

```
AVF info: checkDecoderUsage, vaCodecString: <Gen6> 
AVF info: pp_hw_name: RenderingEngine, id: 3ea, m_pp_nowait: 1
AVF info: RingBufferPool wr:0, rd:108, reset:93, warning:0
```

I saw this error occurs with MacBook Pro, Air, i5/i7 processors etc. Is there any way to solve the stuttering/error messages?

I tested running with `-Dprism.verbose=true` and I saw a major difference between Windows and Mac platforms: on Windows the `Prism platform init order` is `d3d sw` while on Mac it is `es2 sw`; the `Prism pipeline name` is `com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline` and `com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline` respectively.

Maybe a possible solution is to use the same D3D pipeline on Mac? But if running with `-Dprism.order=d3d,sw` it gives `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline`.

I also tried to increase JVM memory with the `-Xms` option but it had no effect. So it really seems to be a codecs issue even though the videos play smoothly on other platforms.

I was testing a Windows generated jar on Mac, so now I also tried to build the AdvancedMedia example on Mac thinking it could make some difference, but nothing changed.

It seems that maybe this is more like a JavaFX bug report than a question.

A little off-topic, but I have to say that before this I tried C++ and VLCj approaches for my application and I changed it only because of Mac functionality issues...

Comment: The option d3d stands for Direct3D and this exists only on Windows. Macs use OpenGL which is used by the es2 pipeline.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, so I will stop trying to use d3d on Mac. So any ideas why Mac's OpenGL is having trouble with JavaFX media? It's strange some questions point out that it should be better than windows. More strange is that it seems nobody ever tested javafx mediaplayer with mp4 videos on Mac before...

Comment: Well, I did a long time ago and did not have any problems. Maybe there is a problem with your specific encoding or maybe the size. Have you tried different mp4s from different sources?

Comment: Yes, I tried multiple mp4 videos including simple sample videos from the internet and they all had the same behaviour. I think that if you used long enough videos you didn't notice anything wrong because the problems which triggers the messages arises in the beginning and just before the video ends. In my application I use shorter videos and it's important that they display correctly until the very end.

Comment: If I use flv videos no errors occur on Mac, so I will see if I can use different formats other than mp4 for my application now.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this bug happens on Mac with any H.264 encoded video, regardless of the file extension. So as described on the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html#SupportedMediaTypes), the only other alternative JavaFX offers is to use VP6 encoding, which is not easy to get - see my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43382513/convert-to-flv-with-vp6-encoding-using-ffmpeg) question - but at least the videos will run smoothly and without any rendering error messages.