# Convert to flv with VP6 encoding using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, flv

I am trying to convert a mov video to flv using vp6 encoding. I tried the following:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mov video.flv
```

However, [it uses the flv1 codec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb8fI.png). I need [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNJZs.png) kind of encoding (Oracle's "oow2010-2.flv" video), which I think uses vp6 or vp6f codec. I searched and it seems people only do decoding from flv/vp6.

By the way, I can't use H.264, it has to be vp6.

Comment: With FFmpeg, it is not possible, since it can only decode VP6. However, you can convert it with [mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu). If you're on linux, you have to do a little trick to get the windows dll to work, but here's a detailed guide how to do that: [link](http://linuxclues.blogspot.hu/2012/05/vp6-mencoder-video-flv-encode-convert.html)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I followed that guide before but somehow I could not find the libwine-dev package and compile with winegcc. But now I managed to convert to vp6 flv using sorenson squeeze encoding software.